# gcc error libSDL missing while using "make"

Tags: compiling, gcc, sdl

I'm trying to compile a program.

I first found out I needed the SDL1.2-devel package so I installed them all (manually, probably didn't do it right).

Before I installed SDL-dev packages, I couldn't run `./configure` (missing sdl error)

Now I can run configure, but when I run `make`, I get this output:

> libtool: link: gcc -g -O2 -I/usr/include/SDL -D_GNU_SOURCE=1 -D_REENTRANT -Wall -g -DPREFIX=\"/usr/local\" -DDATA_PREFIX=\"/usr/local/share\" -o gnujump game.o game-input.o game-output.o game-logic.o game-tools.o game-timer.o main.o menu.o menu-system.o records.o SDL_2dgl.o SDL_rotozoom.o setup.o SFont.o sprite.o surface.o tools.o replay.o effects-trail.o effects-blur.o -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/usr/lib  -L/usr/lib /usr/lib/libSDL.so -lpthread -lSDL_image -lSDL_mixer
>
> **gcc: error: /usr/lib/libSDL.so: No such file or directory**
>
> Makefile:376: fallo en las instrucciones para el objetivo 'gnujump'
>
> make[2]: *** [gnujump] Error 1
>
> make[2]: se sale del directorio '/home/mauro/Sluggy/gnujump-1.0.8/src'
>
> Makefile:357: fallo en las instrucciones para el objetivo 'all-recursive'
>
> make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
>
> make[1]: se sale del directorio '/home/mauro/Sluggy/gnujump-1.0.8'
>
> Makefile:288: fallo en las instrucciones para el objetivo 'all'
>
> make: *** [all] Error 2

(I know it's in spanish. It basically says: "instructions failed" and "leaving directory").

I think the problem may be in the installation of SDL. I did it manually using the package from the official web.

I appreciate help of any kind. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To install `libsdl1.2-dev` in an "official" way, run:

```
sudo apt-get install libsdl1.2-dev
```

After that you might need to run `.configure` again.

---

The `libSDL.so` is not placed directly in the `/usr/lib`. The package from APT configures the path by placing a file in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/`, for example:

```
$ cat /etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu.conf
# Multiarch support
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
```

Comment: I already installed libsdl1.2-dev in all official and unofficial ways possible xD. Ok. So I searched in /usr/lib and found a broken shortcut to "libSDL.so". So It seems all I need to do now is to find the correct file and fix the link. But that file is not in /etc/ld.so.conf.d/. ...

Comment: Now I found it in /usr/local/lib. There was a libSDL.so linking to "libSDL-1.2.so.0.11.4". In /usr/lib I had only the link, not the file, and thus it didn't worked. I copied libSDL-1.2.so.0.11.4 to /usr/lib. It should work now

Comment: Okay so it worked. I still can't compile the damn thing because now make throws a different error, but I guess I'll have to make another thread for that one. Thanks :)